# Maintaining excel formulas centrally

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use many formulas several times in different worksheets. I would like to save all formulas centrally in one worksheet and then simply reference the formula from the other sheets. 
Is there such a possibility?

Comment: i do that but as a function in a XLAM-file

Comment: Could you provide some better example? It's unclear as to what you exactly mean under centrally saving? You want to save a formula (almsot like a cell value) in one worksheet, and load it from that worksheet to another one? or?

Comment: What about creating a template then using and saving from there...

Comment: @Rawrplus: i save the formula as plain text in a cell in a worksheet. every time i need the formula i want to refer to this one cell.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be to create custom/user-defined functions for each formula in VBA and holding them in a central workbook. Then you just refer to the function names in the central workbook (as long as it's open) and you have a shortcut to creating your formulas!

**Here are some resources for how to create custom/user-defined functions:**

- [Microsoft's 'Create Custom Function' documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f)
- [A tutorial on how to make user-defined functions](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html)

**Information for using custom functions in other workbooks:**

> To use a custom function, the workbook containing the module in which you created the function must be open. If that workbook is not open, you get a #NAME? error when you try to use the function. If you reference the function in a different workbook, you must precede the function name with the name of the workbook in which the function resides. For example, if you create a function called DISCOUNT in a workbook called Personal.xlsb and you call that function from another workbook, you must type =personal.xlsb!discount(), not simply =discount().